Uploading files on firebase Storage using Nodejs, Express
I'm trying to upload files (images, pdf) on firebase Storage using firebase functions and express.
So locally as I'm trying with the emulators everything is working fine but in production I'm having an error saying
{
 error1: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[0]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
 at Object.resolve (node:path:1129:7)
 at GoogleAuth.getClient (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:690:39)
 at GoogleAuth.request (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:748:35)
 at Upload.makeRequest (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/cjs/src/resumable-upload.js:744:43)
 at uri.retries (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/cjs/src/resumable-upload.js:410:40)
 at RetryOperation.runAttempt [as _fn] (/workspace/node_modules/async-retry/lib/index.js:42:15)
 at RetryOperation.attempt (/workspace/node_modules/retry/lib/retry_operation.js:116:8)
 at run (/workspace/node_modules/async-retry/lib/index.js:55:8)
 at new Promise (<anonymous>)
 at retry (/workspace/node_modules/async-retry/lib/index.js:58:10) {
 code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
 }

And this is my codebase:
require('dotenv').config();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const _ = require('lodash');
const Joi = require("joi");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const express = require("express");
const formidable = require('formidable-serverless');
const bucket = require('../utils/clouStorage');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const sendEMail = require('../utils/emailService');

const router = express.Router();

const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET || functions.config().jwt.secret;


// DOCTORS REGISTRATION LOGIC
router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {

  // Had to validate the request inputs in the formidable lib because the multipart/form-data
  // was a bit challenging to parse with only the request object.

  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error parsing form data:', err);
      next(err)
      return res.status(500).send("Internal server error");
    }

    const { name, surname, email, phone, gender, password,
      nationalID, passport, citizenship, city, speciality,
      school, school_from, school_to, license_number, yearsOfExperience
    } = fields;

    let doctor;

    const { avatar, license, resume } = files;

    console.log(files);   

    const { error } = validate(fields);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const filesError = validateFile(files);

    if (filesError.error) return res.status(400).send(filesError.error.details[0].message);


    try {
      const doctorSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('doctors').where('email', '==', email).get();
      if (!doctorSnapshot.empty) return res.status(400).send("Doctor already registered.");

      doctor = await admin.auth().createUser({
        email,
        password
      });

      const userId = doctor.uid;
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      const hashed_password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

      let avatarUrl = "";
      let licenseUrl = "";
      let resumeUrl = "";

      // Upload avatar
      if (avatar) {
        const avatarFileName = `${uuidv4()}_${avatar.name}`;
        try {
          console.log({path1: avatar.path})
          const avatarUpload = await bucket.upload(avatar.path, {
            destination: `doctorsImage/${avatarFileName}`,
            metadata: {
              contentType: avatar.type,
            },
          });
          avatarUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${avatarUpload[0].name}`;
        } catch (error) {
          // console.log({ error1: error })
          // return res.status(400).send(error.message);
        }
      }

      // Upload license
      if (license) {
        const licenseFileName = `${uuidv4()}_${license.name}`;
        try {
          console.log({path2: license.path})
          const licenseUpload = await bucket.upload(license.path, {
            destination: `licenses/${licenseFileName}`,
            metadata: {
              contentType: license.type,
            },
          });
          licenseUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${licenseUpload[0].name}`;
        } catch (error) {
          // console.log({ error2: error })
          // return res.status(400).send(error.message);
        }
      }

      // Upload resume
      if (resume) {
        const resumeFileName = `${uuidv4()}_${resume.name}`;
        try {
          console.log({path3: resume.path})
          const resumeUpload = await bucket.upload(resume.path, {
            destination: `resumes/${resumeFileName}`,
            metadata: {
              contentType: resume.type,
            },
          });
          resumeUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${resumeUpload[0].name}`;
        } catch (error) {
          // console.log({ error3: error })
          // return res.status(400).send(error.message);
        }
      };


      await admin.firestore().collection("doctors").doc(userId).set({
        id: userId,
        name,
        surname,
        email,
        phone,
      });

      const adminsSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("admins").get();
      const adminEmails = adminsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().email);

      res.status(201).send({ message: 'Please check you email to verify your account.', userId });
    } catch (error) {
      if (doctor && doctor.uid) {
        await admin.auth().deleteUser(doctor.uid);
      }
      console.log({ error })
      if (error.code) {
        return res.status(400).send(error.message);
      }
      res.status(500).send("Internal server error");
    }
  })
});

But when I'm logging the type of the path, it's showing me a String so I'm not quite sure where the Instance of Object is coming from. I'm using formidable to parse my multipart/formData coming request.
